# achieve full customisation with django forms

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a model with the following fields

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comments = models.TextField()
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
    remind = models.BooleanField()
```

and a modelform

```
class EntryForm(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
```

I want to render a form using bootstrap 3. I can render the form using the same kind of form e.g all fields horizontal or divide them by three in a row. How about more customization. Like

```
 <label title>
 <input title>
 <label comments>
 <input comments>
 <label start>        <label end>
 <input start>        <input end>
 <label remind><input remind>
```

I guess this should be done manually. How can I know to which field of the form i am refering in the template. And by which field i mean is it title, is it comments? Is this correct (suppose the view has passed a form argument to the template) something like

```
<label for={{form.title.auto_id}}>Title</label>
{{form.title}}
```

is that correct? Now i can place what ever div's and arrange form fields as I like correct?Is that the right way? 
How powerfull can a form of django be?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought... Django has extensive, well-written documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

Instead of guessing random things you could just read the docs.

Additionally there are a number of Django apps designed to simplify outputting form HTML in a Bootstrap style, such as:

https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3 (recommended)
https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit
https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form